# Zsh doesn't see some CLI

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-terminal, zsh

I've just installed Zsh / oh-my-zsh to apply some style and helpful functions to my terminal but it isn't working well.

Here what I did:

```
sudo apt install zsh
```

and then I cloned oh-my-zsh with:

```
git clone https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh.git ~/.oh-my-zsh
```

Created zsh configuration with:

```
cp ~/.oh-my-zsh/templates/zshrc.zsh-template ~/.zshrc
```

And last, changed default Shell with `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.

After all, I tried to use my terminal like I use it everyday and the `npm`, for example, isn't working with zsh but with bash only.

Here a print with what I saying:

[image: Printscreen]

When I switch from zsh to bash, I can see everything working well. And if I turn back to zsh, continue working.

But if I just open my terminal (in zsh) and try to the npm version, this is what I see.

So, how can I fix this and use zsh totally unconcerned?

I use Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: What's the output of `whereis npm` in bash?

Comment: @Hi-Angel `npm: /home/gabriel/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin/npm`

Answer (score 0):

`npm` doesn't work for you in zsh because you don't have it in $PATH, which in turn is because it's not from the Ubuntu repository. If you execute in bash `whereis npm`, you'll find that it's installed in `/home/gabriel/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin/npm`. This means you've downloaded it from somewhere, and then updated bash configuration *(most likely the `~/.bashrc` file)* to add this local installation to $PATH. So, now you need to transfer this part to `~/.zshrc` *(you can just copy-paste that line, zsh is bash-compatible)*. The line may probably look like:

```
export PATH=$HOME/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin/npm:$PATH
```

Note though, if you update this local npm binary, the `v10.15.3` part is gonna get changed. So you probably want to use a symbolic link to latest npm binary.